# how to “extract” values from a column, in which values are found in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1`:

| ID | item |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | chair |
| 11112 | desk¥blue chair |
| 11113 | bed¥pen¥cable |
| 11114 | mug¥old sofa¥toy |
| 11115 | old mug¥wine glass |
| 11116 | blue chair¥old mug |

etc.

and a large dictionary `item_dict` (from csv) which categorize some but not all items into categories:

| item | category |
| --- | --- |
| chair | furniture |
| blue chair | furniture |
| mug | tableware |
| old mug | tableware |
| wine glass | tableware |

etc.

The goal is to make a new column in `df1` of all category of interest for items, if any, in each row:

| ID | item | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | chair | furniture |
| 11112 | desk¥blue chair | furniture |
| 11113 | bed¥pen¥cable |  |
| 11114 | mug¥old sofa¥toy | mug |
| 11115 | old mug¥wine glass | mug |
| 11116 | blue chair¥old mug | furniture, mug |

I’ve tried

```
df1[‘category’] = df1[‘item’].replace(item_dict)
```

which will only replace values that only have a single item;

adding `regex=True` would allow multi-item entries to be replaced but would turn `desk¥blue chair` into `desk¥blue furniture` bc a shorter one existed.

I know `replace` isn’t the best option since I want the new column to only contain categories of interest without other item names, but am unsure of what to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# !pip install -U swifter  #### only in case of very large dataframe
import swifter


delimiter = '¥'
df1['category'] = df1['item'].swifter.apply(
    lambda _: delimiter.join([item_dict.get(el, '') for el in _.split(delimiter)])
)
```